# The reason why Thevenin voltage source is in SERIES with Thevenin resistor and why Norton current source is in PARALLEL with Norton resistor

Tags: thevenin, norton

As you know, in Thevenin's theorem Thevenin voltage source is in series with Thevenin resistor and in Norton's theorem Norton current source is in parallel with Norton resistor. COULDN'T Thevenin voltage source be in PARALLEL with Thevenin resistor and Norton current source be in SERIES with Norton resistor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the Thevenin source were in parallel, the output voltage would be constant.  Ditto for Norton source/current.  A two-port linear network containing only resistances, current sources, and/or voltage sources will have a single open circuit voltage and single short circuit current which are linearly related.  Putting a voltage source in parallel with a resistance will give you a constant output voltage regardless of current and also implies infinite short circuit current when the output is shorted.  Putting a current source in series with a resistance will give you a constant output current and implies infinite open circuit voltage.

Comment: What do you mean by "OUTPUT voltage"?

Comment: The voltage across the combination of voltage/current source and Thevenin/Norton resistance.

Comment: It doesn't *have* to be anything, but it won't be the electrical equivalent of the circuit it's representing.

Comment: The assumption for Thevenin/Norton equivalents is that the sources are ideal.  I.e. voltage sources maintain the same voltage across their terminals regardless of the current flowing through them; current sources maintain the same current flowing through them regardless of the voltage across their terminals.

Answer (score 0):

See Occam's Razor. We use Norton and Thevenin equivalents because they are the most useful and convenient minimal structures for subsequent circuit analysis. If you adopt different circuit configurations, they will not be 'Thevenin' or 'Norton', and may not even be viable, as is the case here.